# in a recursive method, find index of largest value in an array

Tags: java, arrays, recursion

//as the title says, i need to find the index of the largest value in an int //array, all of this needs to be done in one method this is what my helper //method looks like so far

it only returns last index in array i can easily return the max value but i cant figure out how to return the index of that value

//this is helper method

```
private int recursiveGetIndexOfLargest( int[] list, int count )
{
    int index;  
    int[] y = list;
    int temp = count - 1;
    if( count > 0 )
    {
        index = Math.max( list[list.length - 1], list[temp] );
        for(int x = 0; x < y.length; x++)
        {
            if(y[x] == index)
            {
                return x;
            }
        }
        return recursiveGetIndexOfLargest(list, temp);
    }

    else
    {
        return -1;//empty list
    }        
}
```

this is method that calls helper

```
public int getIndexOfLargest()
{
    return recursiveGetIndexOfLargest(list, count);
}
```

Comment: i cannot change the parameter to either method

Comment: what is the question?

Comment: It has to be an array? Because you actually need a full pass through the array to find the element, that is O(n).

Comment: I would imagine that you didn't mean to return the looping variable, but instead meant to return y[x]?

Comment: no i need to return index at which the highest value occurs so if array is {1,5,2,3,0} i need to return 1

Answer (score 1):

Try this one:

```
 int recursiveGetIndexOfLargest(int[] list, int count)
 {
   if (count == list.length - 1) return count;

   int index = recursiveGetIndexOfLargest(list, count + 1);
   return list[count] > list[index] ? count : index;
 }

 int[] arr = {1, 5, 2, 3, 0};
 System.out.println(recursiveGetIndexOfLargest(arr, 0));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
int findLargestIndex(int[] array, int currentPos, int currentLargestIndex)
{
  if(currentPos == array.length) 
      return currentLargestIndex;
  if(array[currentPost] > array[currentLargestIndex]
      return findLargestIndex(array,currentPos+1, currentPos);
  else
      return findLargestIndex(array,currentPos+1, currentLargestIndex);
}
```

It is actually a O(n) for loop done recursively.
You start it like this:

```
int result = findLargestIndex(array,0,0);
```

This would work but it will alter the array.

```
void findLargestIndex(int[] array, int currentPos)
{
     if(currentPos == array.size()) return;
     array[0] = (array[currentPos] < array[currenPos + 1] ? currentPos + 1 : currentPos;
     findLargestIndex(int[] array, currentPos + 1);
}
```

The largest index will be storred at array[0] (This alters the array).

You simply start the function:

```
 findLargestIndex(array,0);
```

---

Comment: i cant change the parameter of the method it has to stay ( int[] list, int count )

Comment: Ok give me a second then. Can you use a field to store the currentLargestIndex or is it a algorithmic problem solving question?

Comment: lol i cant alter the array because right after that method i need to call another method that reverses the order of the array recursively

Comment: Then let me try a moving window approach.

Comment: I don't think it is possible without altering the array, because I will have to swap two elements. Is this a homework? Can I get the full problem statement?

Comment: yes its a homework prob, rule is i cant change parameter or use any other method to achieve result and i have to use recursion, and this is the suggested algorithm-
Find the largest value in that portion of the array containing all but the last element.  Compare that value to the value in the last element and return the index of the larger of the two.

Comment: And you have to do it recursively. Cause it doesnt say u cannot alter the array. You can do a similar approach like the one above, but storing the largest index in the last element of the array.

Comment: yes i must use recursion, the program is already written out the only thing im allowed to touch is whats inside that method(not including parameter)and the reverse order method, if i alter the array the reverse order method(which i already finished and it works) wont produce correct output

Answer (score 0):

Thank You tomse!!!!!!!!

the parameter count is actually the size of the array so i changed it a little to

```
private int recursiveGetIndexOfLargest( int[] list, int count )
{
    int index;
    int temp = count - 1;
    if( temp == 0 )
    {
        return temp;
    }

    else
    {
        index = recursiveGetIndexOfLargest(list, temp);
        return list[temp] > list[index] ? temp : index;
    }
}
```

and now it works damn i wasted several hours failing